# MySQL Grant All Commands?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install daisy and I am following their install guide and running these commands as localhost root:

```
CREATE DATABASE daisyrepository CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
GRANT ALL ON daisyrepository.* TO daisy@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'daisy';
GRANT ALL ON daisyrepository.* TO daisy@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'daisy';
CREATE DATABASE activemq CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
GRANT ALL ON activemq.* TO activemq@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'activemq';
GRANT ALL ON activemq.* TO activemq@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'activemq';
```

The databases are created successfully but each of my GRANT ALL commands completes but it shows 0 records updated:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO daisy@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'daisy';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I am running into a problem in the future of the install guide that seems to be related to this section. What am I doing wrong?

Additional info in the install guide about this section if it helps:
Now create the necessary databases, users and access rights by entering (or copy-paste) the commands below in the mysql client. What follows behind the IDENTIFIED BY is the password for the user, which you can change if you wish. The daisy@localhost entries are necessary because otherwise the default access rights for anonymous users @localhost will take precedence. If you'll run MySQL on the same machine as the Daisy Repository Server, you only need the @localhost entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Everything is fine. The query haven't returned any rows and didn't affect any rows (only explicit DML queries affect rows) - so you get 0

Comment: Thanks zerkms, but when I try and start up the application I get this error:  "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access
denied for user 'activemq'@'localhost' (using password: YES))".  I have never set a password to YES so I am confused by that.  Any ideas?

Comment: @roacha: `using password: YES` means that some password has been used, but because of security reasons it hasn't been displayed to you back